# How to host Symfony 4 projects on Plesk Onyx

Tags: git, hosting, staging, symfony4, plesk-onyx

I'm searching for a hosting company where I could host my Symfony 4 projects. I've found a dutch hosting company TransIP where the offer a VPS X1 with Plesk Onyx.

My question is it possible to run a Symfony 4 app on Plesk without changing configuration?

Any other suggestions are welcome to. I look for something where i easly could manage my websites. Also preferance a easy setup for stating and git deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is totally posible to run a Symfony 4 Application using Plesk. Make sure you're using Plesk Onyx 17.5.3 or higher. This because Symfony 4 requires PHP 7.1 and it's only shipped from version 17.5.3.

All you have to do is make sure your Document root directory in Plesk is pointing to the Symfony `public` folder.

If you need more detail, take a quick look at this post: https://victorcruz.me/deploying-symfony-4-application-in-plesk/